# Importing React Native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know there are several questions about this, but I can't seem to find any that solves my issue, then I ask, why isn't this working?

I've tried:

```
import Row from '../Row';
import Row from './src/components/Row';
import Row from 'Row';
import Row from '../../components/Row';
```

So, here is my project file structure:

- src

  - components

    - MainList
    - Row
  - screens

etc.

So I'm trying to import Row into MainList.js, without any success, the error which changes with each path I enter on the import goes:

*Unable to resolve "../Row" from "src\components\MainList.js"*

Thank you very much.

PS: I should clarify I'm exporting Row with

```
export default Row;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MainList.js` is staying at the same directory with `Row.js`. Hence the correct syntax should be:

```
import Row from './Row';
```

Since I noticed that you're trial and error, just a side note:

1. `..` means going back one level from the directory of your current file.
2. `./` is referring to the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in the same directory you can import like this :

```
import Row from './Row'
```